# Firefox override NetError.xhtml page

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-12.04

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, and my firefox version is 47.0. I want to override the netError.xhtml file. I have tried googling a lot, but unable to fix this problem

This is what I've done so far

> from my home directory

`unzip /usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -d omni`

> edited the function `retryThis(buttonEl)` infile
>   /home/suman/omni/chrome/toolkit/content/global/netError.xhtml

```
  function retryThis(buttonEl)
  {
    // Note: The application may wish to handle switching off "offline mode"
    // before this event handler runs, but using a capturing event handler.

    // Session history has the URL of the page that failed
    // to load, not the one of the error page. So, just call
    // reload(), which will also repost POST data correctly.
    try {
      location.replace('http://www.google.com');
    } catch (e) {
      // We probably tried to reload a URI that caused an exception to
      // occur;  e.g. a nonexistent file.
    }

    buttonEl.disabled = true;
  }
```

Repacked the omni folder and replace it into the actual location

```
zip -qr9XD omni.ja *
mv home/suman/omni/omni.ja /usr/lib/firefox/
```

Restarted the browser and generated the page as show in image description below

But I cannot redirect it to google site when **Try Again** is clicked

**Any help would be very much appreciated**

Below is the screenshot

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLFK7.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have similiar problem in firefox 59 in windows 10.

**TLDR**: check `chrome.manifest` in the folder `mozilla firefox/browser/omni.ja/chrome` and you can delete the line that override `netError.xhtml` with `aboutNetError.xhtml` or you can simply edit aboutNetError.xhtml.

I get the idea[1] that there's a rule that override `neterror.dpd` in `chrome.manifest` because the `neterror.dpd` in `omni.ja` from Mozilla Firefox folder is different from the error message I found when an error occured when I'm browsing.

So I look into all the `chrome.manifest` that i can find but I didn' find any that override the rule. So I searched for the possibility of another omni.ja and therw i found it in `Mozilla Firefox/browser`
So what I do is:

1. Copy `omni.ja` to Desktop or any of your preferred folder and rename it to `omni.zip`
2. Extract the archive to a folder (I named it `omni` too)
3. Get into the folder `omni/browser/chrome/browser/content`
4. There I found `aboutNetError
   xhtml` and this is the file that you want to edit

[1]https://mike.kaply.com/2012/06/14/customizing-firefox-hiding-private-browsing-continued/